# make next_posts_link() return an absolute URL

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress `next_posts_link();` returns `http://currenturl.com/currentpage**/page/x/**`.
What could I add in functions.php to return `http://baseurl.com/page/x/` in all cases, so an absolute URL without just adding /page/x/ to the current page.

Thanks for your ideas guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is your friend:

```
$test = 'http://example.com/test';
$test = preg_replace('/^http:\/\/.*?(\/.*)/', "http://baseurl.com$1", $test);
echo $test;
```

Adjust to suit your needs. It might be worthwhile defining your base url as a constant and encapsulating this functionality in a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . next_posts_link();
```

Output: http://baseurl.com/page/x/

Comment: sorry, I havn't been clear enough. next_posts_link() return http://THECURRENTURL.com/page/x/ so that is not an option :(